# sfWidgetFormDate - only 40 days to future and 0 to the past

Tags: php, datetime, symfony1, symfony-1.4

```
$years = range(2009, 2020);
$month = range ???;
$days = range ???;

$w = new sfWidgetFormDate(
  array('years' => array_combine($years, $years),
        'month' => array_combine($month, $month),
        'days' => array_combine($days, $days),
)
);
```

how can i make in this example 0 days to the past and 40 to future with actually date?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$years = array_unique(array(date('Y'), date('Y', strtotime('+40 days'))));
$months = array_unique(array(date('m'), date('m', strtotime('first day of next month')), date('m', strtotime('+40 days'))));
$days = range(date('d'), 31);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
format('Y'); $yr_init = $yr_actual-10; $years = range($yr_actual,$yr_init); 
$this->widgetSchema['bcg_1'] = new sfWidgetFormDate(array('format' => 
    '%day%/%month%/%year%','years'=>array_combine($years, $years))); ?>
```